# How to remove() a sequence of String elements in an ArrayList() using indices in java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, indexing

I want to remove the 4 indices in sequence string elements in my code here.
My ArrayList contains multiple String elements:

```
{MyString,MyString1,MyString2,MyString3,MyString4,...., MyString10}
```

This is my code:

```
String removedItem = "MyString";

for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {  
    if (myArrayList.get(i).equals(removedItem)) {
        myArrayList.remove(i);
        myArrayList.remove(i+1);
        myArrayList.remove(i+2);
        myArrayList.remove(i+3);
    }
}

System.out.println(myArrayList);
```

My code doesn't seem to remove the first 4 indices in order. What am I doing wrong and how do I do fix it? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you only have to remove 4 elements, you can use this: `int index = myArrayList.indexOf(removedItem); myArrayList.subList(index, index + 4).clear();` (you need to check though if `index` is smaller than `0` if the list doesn't contain the element)

Comment: Your current code doesn't work, because you remove the element at index `i`, then all of the elements with a greater index will be moved down by `1` to fill the gap, so you'd have to simply call `myArrayList.remove(i)` for it to work. Another way would be to change the order, so first delete element at `i+3` then `i+2` etc

Comment: As I see you are trying to remove the strings that contain "MyString" from the list?

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, you want to remove the first four elements from list equals to `removeditem`? If there are more than four, the fifth, the sixth, etc. will remain in the list ?

Comment: What you are currently doing is: if an item **equals the `removedItem`** then remove that and its 3 successors. You don't even check if those successors acutally exist (if the list really has those indexes). **Your current code will not remove the items because they don't equal the `removedItem`, which is `"MyString"` and all the items in the list are containing it but aren't equal to it because of numbers appended.**

Comment: @M.Ismail Yes! I want to remove the string that contains "MyString" and the following 3 strings after it

Comment: In addition, due to the missing check for existing indexes, you will get an `Exception` as soon as you change `equals(removedItem)` to `contains(removedItem)` in the if statement in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete the specified value and the next three elements.You can use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {  
    if (myArrayList.get(i).equals(removedItem)) {
        myArrayList.remove(i);
        myArrayList.remove(i);
        myArrayList.remove(i);
        myArrayList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Because every time you delete an element, the next element moves forward.

Answer (score 0):

Because when with each remove call the size of the list will be decreased by one.
To trace this you can use breakpoints at remove calls.

For example, if your ArrayList is initialized with 4 elements.
{MyString,MyString1,MyString2,MyString3}

when `i = 0`:

- After calling `myArrayList.remove(0);` MyString will be removed and the size of `myArrayList` will be 3 {MyString1,MyString2,MyString3}.
- After calling `myArrayList.remove(1);` this will remove the `MyString2` not `MyString1` `{MyString1,MyString3}`.
- `myArrayList.remove(2);` this will throw Exception

You can use Iterator and safely check with `hasNext()` method or use the code provided by Mr.HE answer and safely check that `elemnt != null` before removing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
String removedItem = "MyString";

int remove = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < myArrayList.size(); i++) {  
    if (myArrayList.get(i).contains(removedItem)) {
        myArrayList.remove(i);
        i--;
        remove++;
        if(remove == 4) {
            System.out.println(myArrayList);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

If you change your myArrayList value and removedItem value it will work also.